# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011/2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

In my entity (A) has 50 option set. If the user select 10 optionsset value and not selected remaining one, and he/she click save button. In that situation i need to alert user "To fill all the option set". I don't want to get the Schema name for the optionset individually, i need to get all the option set schema name dynamically.

Is it possible? Help me.

Comment: you have 50 OptionSets or your OptionSet have 50 Options ?

Comment: i have 50 option set. Not 50 Options.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this function, but you can try this and make changes if needed.

```
function IsFormValidForSaving(){
var valid = true;
var message = "Following fields are required fields: \n";

    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) {
        if (attribute.getRequiredLevel() == "required") {
            if(attribute.getValue() == null){

                var control = attribute.controls.get(0);

                // Cheking if Control is an optionset and it is not hidden
                if(control.getControlType() == "optionset" && control.getVisible() == true) {
                    message += control.getLabel() + "\n";
                }

                valid = false; 
            }
        }
    });

    if(valid == false)
    {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

Ref: [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Validate required form javascript](http://dynamicslollipops.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-validate.html)

Comment: This will check all fields, not just optionsets, and also hidden fields.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs yes you are right, I missed the point that he want to validate only optionsets. I have updated my answer. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Required fields individual alert fire before the on save event. If you wish to prevent the single alert routine for all unfilled option sets you need to remove the requirement constraint and manage the constraint yourself, probably in your on save handler. I’m just writing the idea here (not tested).

```
// enter all optionsets ids
var OptionSets50 = ["new_optionset1","new_optionset2","new_optionset50"];     
var dirtyOptions  = [];

function MyOptionSet(id) {
   var mos  = this;
   var Obj = Xrm.Page.getAttribute(id);
   var Ctl = Xrm.Page.getControl(id);

   Obj.addOnChange(
    function () {
        if (Obj.getValue() != null)
             delete dirtyOptions[id];       
        else 
             dirtyOptions[id] = mos;
   });

   this.GetLabel = function() {
      return Ctl.getLabel();
   }

   if (Obj.getValue() == null) 
       dirtyOptions[id] = mos;
}

function OnCrmPageLoad() { 
   for(var x in OptionSets50) {
       OptionSets50 [x] = new MyOptionSet(OptionSets50 [x]);
   }

   Xrm.Page.data.entity.addOnSave(OnCrmPageSave);
}

//check for dirty options and alert 
function OnCrmPageSave(execContext) {
   var sMsg = "The following Optinsets Are Required: ";
   var sLen = sMsg.length;
   for(var os in dirtyOptions) {
       sMsg += dirtyOptions[os].GetLabel() + "\n";
   }

   if (sMsg.length > sLen) {
       execContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
       alert(sMsg);
   }
}
```

Comment: Make sure all option sets ids are correct in OptionSet50. 
Obj will work only if the Xrm.Page.getAttribute(id) returns the field object. Debug the code if necessary.

Comment: Made the necessary changes.